# AzureAD PowerShell - how to read CountryCode, DistinguishedName, middleName, msExchRecipientDisplayType, msRTCSIP-Line and other attributes

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

We are syncing on-prem AD to Azure AD using AzureADConnect and need to verify that the following attributes from on-prem AD are syncing successfully. Can you please help with the PowerShell commands, which can help with fetching these attributes?

- cn
- countryCode
- DisplayNamePrintable
- middleName
- mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid
- msExchImmutableId
- msExchRecipientDisplayType
- msRTCSIP-Line
- msRTCSIP-OptionFlags
- msRTCSIP-UserEnabled

I've already tried to fetch them using `Get-AzureADUser, Get-Mailbox, Get-AzureADUserManager, Get-MsolUser`. Result of trial:

[image: trial of Get-AzureADUser]

Comment: With `Get-AzureADUser` should be possible to see those attribute, not 100% sure if all of them but most of them probably.

Comment: I've tried `Get-AzureAdUser  -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'test@test.com'" | fl` and `Get-AzureAdUser  -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'test@test.com'" | Select-Object middleName, mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid` hasn't worked at all :(

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I've added output from one of my trials to the post as well.

Comment: You're right. Take a look at this doc, might be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized

Comment: Is middle name included in the `displayName`?

Comment: Nope, that's a separate attribute.